# How to save firefox profiles to a folder using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-profile

When i load a firefox profile into a selenium webdriver like this:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('c:/profile_folder_path')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe', firefox_profile=fp)
```

it loads the profile fine and it works. But in situation where you pass an empty folder to `FirefoxProfile()`
like:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('c:/empty_path')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe', firefox_profile=fp)
```

it doesn't create a new profile like chrome, edge and opera.

**On Chrome**

```
options = Options()
# This will save a new profile to the path if a profile is not there
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir="C:/empty_path"')
```

It also works on Edge and Opera.

Why doesn't it work on firefox and is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Please read [mre] and show code that we could copy and paste, without modification, to exhibit the problem.

Comment: I modified it a little hopefully its helps to explain the issue